# Homebrew: How to ignore cask formula on `brew upgrade`? (since `pin` has no `--cask` option)

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source

I hope there is a command equivalent for casks that works to ignore updates on main line packages.

```
brew upgrade --ignore <FORMULA>
```

This Stack Overflow question from 2014 has multiple answers that mention `brew pin` as a solution, but that feature does not work for casks:

- [Ignore formula on brew upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093918/ignore-formula-on-brew-upgrade)

**How is it possible to ignore a formula by name while upgrading packages in Homebrew with `brew upgrade`?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Workaround

You can use [`buo/homebrew-cask-ugrade`](https://github.com/buo/homebrew-cask-upgrade), which is a third-party tool with extra `cask` upgrade features, including `pin`.

```
brew tap buo/cask-upgrade    # Install `brew-cask-upgrade`
brew cu pin <CASK_NAME>      # Pin the cask you want
```

## Reason for workaround

It looks like the Homebrew maintainer will not allow pinning of casks, because many casks auto-update, which Homebrew technically can't prevent from happening.

From a [comment on homebrew/homebrew-cask: Allow pinning casks #49127](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/49127#issuecomment-401501245):

> A huge chunk of casks auto-update and we can’t stop that. So pin would at best be inconsistent and not work in a lot of cases.

Comment: Yes, this is great... but what about casks that doesn't auto-upgrade AND you absolutely DO NOT want to upgrade them (I think of eclipse-java... when using `brew upgrade` it breaks your install).

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you want to fix that issue specifically, I'd switch to IntelliJ IDEA. It's much better than eclipse and doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Honestly, I tried a few times IntelliJ over the recent years, and I hate it; to me, it's no better than Eclipse, I found it's just another over-complicated bloated IDE... and as I'm used to Eclipse for more than 15 years now, I don't find any reason to change. Or maybe for VS Code... ah ah!!! but we're OT here...

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks, worked like a charm to avoid these minor upgrades to libreoffice that took ages for a tool I don't use much.

Comment: For those wondering what the "cu" in "brew cu pin <CASK_NAME>" is, it is only available once the cask-upgrade tap is installed. Just click the link above for buo/homebrew-cask-ugrade and it explains further.

Comment: Does `brew cu` upgrade only casks or also classic formulae? From what I have read on github page it manages only casks. If so this does not help so much :-D

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to write some BASH code, this can be done in a one liner using `brew list` and `grep --invert-match`:

```
brew upgrade $(brew list | grep --invert-match <FORMULA>)
```

Essentially, we just filter the list of packages installed by brew and filter the one called *<FORMULA>* using grep's inverted matching.

Tested with brew 3.4.3 on GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20).

Comment: Just used this, great answer. To be precise I use it for casks, but it would work for formulae just as well. I read an environment variable from a list of casks to be ignored like this: `BREW_CASK_IGNORELIST=$(awk '{print $1}' .brew-upgrade-cask-ignorelist | paste -s -d"|" - |sed "s/\|/\\\|/g")`; followed by `brew upgrade --cask --greedy --force $(brew list --cask | grep --invert-match --regexp $BREW_CASK_IGNORELIST)`.

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff's answer is very close to what I use to prevent certain casks from upgrading, and it works great.

Answer (score 7):

I discovered a much nicer solution for this:

Add `auto_updates true` to the cask file that you want to exclude from `brew upgrade`. This way, the cask is still fully managed by brew and can even be upgraded by using `brew upgrade --greedy`.

---

old answer

> I found another workaround that will also somewhat work with `brew upgrade` by simply removing the Cask file from `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks`.
>
> After removing the file, brew no longer checks the cask for updates and therefore does not even list it in `brew upgrade` anymore. Keep in mind that this will definitely break all other operations with this cask.
>
> My issue was that I had to pin the version of a JDK as brew would try to upgrade it to a newer version which was not available in production yet. Therefore I deleted the `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/temurin.rb` file.

Comment: Genius answer!
Works better than modifying the cask file with a different version number, because that gets clobbered every global update.

Comment: Worked to prevent Homebrew from upgrading LibreOffice to 7.5.0 on my macOS 10.13 machine. Before the modification, `brew outdated` listed `libreoffice (7.4.5) != 7.5.0`. After the modification, it lists nothing.

Comment: Asking for clarification: Adding `auto_updates true` to the cask file means modifying the .json file located in `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/someapp/.metadata/1.2.3/20231029082329.680/Casks/someapp.json` ?

Answer (score 2):

Does brew know or care that internet thinks that `pin` is removed? :-)

My brew (3.3.12, last commit 2022-01-26) does know nothing about it. From `man brew`

```
pin installed_formula [...]
       Pin the specified formula, preventing them from being upgraded when issuing the brew upgrade
       formula command. See also unpin.

upgrade [options] [outdated_formula|outdated_cask ...]
       Upgrade outdated casks and outdated, unpinned formulae using the same options they were
       originally installed with, plus any appended brew formula options. If cask or formula are
       specified, upgrade only the given cask or formula kegs (unless they are pinned; see pin, unpin).
```

Documentation seems to be in par with reality as I was able to pin, output pinned list and unpin:

```
+ > brew pin fzf
+ > brew list --pinned
fzf
+ > brew unpin fzf
+ > brew list --pinned
+ >
```

Whether `pin` is what you want or need is another story, but rumors that `pin` is removed are greatly exaggerated.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken when I said "removed". I had meant that `pin` doesn't work for casks, since there is no `--cask` option and casks aren't mentioned in `pin`'s `--help` or the man page.

Answer (score 2):

A seemingly safer variation of [Max's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444006) is to delete the relevant folders in `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/`.

This seems to cause brew to forget it installed them (e.g. they no longer appear in `brew list`, but without messing with brew's library internals.