# Cannot pin homebrew formula mactex

Tags: mac, homebrew

I am unable to pin MacTeX in Terminal with the command `brew pin mactex`:

[image]

It would ordinarily be not a problem.  However when I try to upgrade formulas using `brew upgrade` or `brew upgrade --cask` it tries to upgrade MacTeX also, which I do not want. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When adding Terminal output, please copy/paste as text and format as code, it's much easier to read that way (and also accessible to people using screen readers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacTeX is installed as a Homebrew cask, casks can't be pinned though (see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/49127#issuecomment-401501245 and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/90242)

> A huge chunk of casks auto-update and we can’t stop that. So pin would at best be inconsistent and not work in a lot of cases.

There is a user-written extension called [homebrew-cask-upgrade](https://github.com/buo/homebrew-cask-upgrade) which seems to address this issue, but I have no experience with it and it may bring along other issues.

For your specific scenario, I would just install MacTeX directly from [TUG](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) and avoid any auto-updating triggered by Homebrew. Or, if you don't need the GUI applications bundled with MacTeX, use `brew install texlive` which just installs the non-GUI binaries and can be pinned.

Comment: Is it really MacTeX that is installed by Homebrew or TeX Live?

Comment: @HerbSchulz See first few lines of the respective [cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/mactex.rb). MacTeX **is** TeX Live with macOS GUI components. But there is `brew install texlive` which doesn't include the GUI parts.

Comment: MacTeX also installs a data structure that running apps in Terminal easy and standardizes GUI setup.

Comment: Thank you @nohillside and HerbSchulz. In the future I will be switching to Linux and I hope with the new experience will come new niggles and issues. Hehe. For the present I am only upgrading the formulae that needs to be upgraded by name.

Answer (score -1):

I posted [another workaround](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444006/465153).

You can simply remove the cask file. Keep in mind that this will break all other operations with this cask.